# How to make this kind of table in HTML

Tags: html

How can I make this table using html?

[image]

A1 and A2 (as Bs and Cs) have the same width. I was trying to do something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         A1
      </td>
      <td>
         B1
      </td>
      <td>
         C1
      </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- new table goes here -->
   <tr>
      <td>
         A2
      </td>
      <td>
         B2
      </td>
      <td>
         C2
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

But inner table makes A1 row wider. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily using collspan:

```
   <tr>
       <td colspan="3">between</td>
    </tr>
```

see fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/09w8pqhz/

Answer (score 1):

Like this [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/08ggunav/) ?

```html
<table border = "1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         A1
      </td>
      <td>
         B1
      </td>
      <td>
         C1
      </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- new table goes here -->
    <tr>
      <td colspan = "3">
         A1
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>
         A2
      </td>
      <td>
         B2
      </td>
      <td>
         C2
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```